# improve efficiency of filling dataset with sampling

Tags: r, performance, probability, sampling

Given `myletters`:

```
library(tidyverse)
myletters <- letters
myletters
#  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

I want to sample 4 letters at a time (without replacement) from `myletters`, repeat this `X` multiple times and find the probability of having sampled all letters at least once in `X = 1:100` draws.

For example if `X = 10` we could get:

```
set.seed(10)
X <- unlist(rerun(10, sample(myletters, 4, replace = F)))
X
#  [1] "k" "i" "j" "p" "l" "w" "h" "v" "g" "s" "x" "o" "o" "j" "g" "y" "b" "x" "m" "h" "n" "g" "f" "y" "v" "r" "u" "y" "m" "e" "a" "g" "z" "r" "d" "y" "x" "s" "v"
# [40] "r"

#test if X contains all 26 letters
n_distinct(X) == 26 #26 = no of letters
#FALSE
```

The following approach does what I want in a simulation but doesn't scale very well as it fills a dataframe column with up to 400 letters in a cell so is awkward and inefficient:

```
output <- crossing(drawsX = 1:100,
                       trial = 1:100) %>%
  mutate(draws_output = map(drawsX, ~ unlist(rerun(., sample(myletters, 4, replace = F)))),
         all_letters = map_lgl(draws_output, ~ n_distinct(.) == 26))
output

#plot
output %>%
  group_by(drawsX) %>%
  summarise(prob_of_all_letters = mean(all_letters)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(drawsX, prob_of_all_letters)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  labs(y = "Probability")
```

Ideally I would like to simulate more times  e.g. `trial = 1:100000` but the approach above is inefficient if I wanted to do this.

**1)** Is there a more efficient way to fill my dataset (or using a matrix) with samples?

**2)** Also, is there an analytic way to solve this problem in R instead of simulation. e.g. what is probability of get 26 letters from 10 draws of 4 samples each?

thanks

Comment: Drawing the samples is almost certainly not your bottleneck. You should profile your code to see what is actually the slow part before trying to speed up individual pieces. If it were me, I would write a function that takes `X` and `myletters` as input, and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Using a `matrix` internally to that function will probably be faster than a data frame. Then you can `replicate` (or `rerun`, if you prefer) that function for each trial, and only store the `TRUE` or `FALSE` results, rather than storing X draw from each of 100000 trials, which seems like a waste of memory.

Comment: And yes, there probably is an analytic solution. You could ask on math.stackexchange or stats.stackexchange for help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat improved version. The code is a bit more efficient and certainly cleaner:

```
sample_sets = function(replicates, k, set = letters) {
  draws = vapply(1:replicates, function(z, ...) sample.int(...), FUN.VALUE = integer(k), n = length(set), size = k, replace = FALSE)
  all(seq_along(set) %in% draws)
}

## example use
output <- crossing(
    drawsX = 1:100,
    trial = 1:100
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    outcome = map_lgl(drawsX, sample_sets, set = letters, k = 4),
  )

## timing
system.time({output <- crossing(
    drawsX = 1:100,
    trial = 1:100
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    outcome = map_lgl(drawsX, sample_sets, set = letters, k = 4),
  )
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.79    0.04    2.95 


## original way
system.time({output <- crossing(drawsX = 1:100,
                       trial = 1:100) %>%
  mutate(draws_output = map(drawsX, ~ unlist(rerun(., sample(letters, 4, replace = F)))),
         all_letters = map_lgl(draws_output, ~ n_distinct(.) == 26))})
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.96    0.06    5.18
```

So it's about 40% faster on this data - hopefully that performance gain will continue as `draws` increases.